# Simple algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I am over thinking this, I think it's easy and I am making some silly mistake.

$$2500 = 4a^2$$

I know the answer is $-5$ and $5$

But I can't find the proper steps.

$$2500 = 4a^2\\
2500/4 \implies (4a^2)/4 = 625 = a^2$$
I then would take the square root of both sides, and I think that's where my error is.

Comment: The answer is definitely not $\pm 5$. The square root of $625$ is $\pm 25$.

Comment: $2500=4a\iff50^2=(2a)^2\iff|50|=|2a|\iff50=2|a|\iff25=\pm a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{2500}{4}=a^2\\
\implies 25\times\dfrac{100}{4}=a^2\\
\implies a=\sqrt{25}\times\sqrt{\dfrac{100}{4}}=\sqrt{25}\times\sqrt{25}\\
\implies a=\pm25$$
Your method is right. Just take the square root to get $a=\pm25$.

Comment: @GeekyDewd I'm sorry to say that they're wrong.

Comment: I typed it in again and it is saying the answer you have, I don't know what happened, but thank you.

Comment: @GeekyDewd No problem.